# Finding the Lagrangian from the derivative of position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

I have to find the Lagrangian for a system.
In the point of interest I have come up with the following position coordinates:

$$x = Rcos(\omega t)+\ell sin(\phi)$$
and
$$y = Rsin(\omega t)-\ell cos(\phi)$$
Now, since I want to find the Lagrangian I need to take the derivative with respect to $t$ of both of them (To get the $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$), and plug it into the formula for kinetic energy. Although it seems easy, the result I should get I'm a little confused about.

In my opinion only the first term in each equation is the only ones that is dependent of $t$, but I know that the answer should be:

$$\dot{x} = -R \omega sin(\omega t)+\ell cos(\phi)\dot{\phi}$$
and
$$\dot{y} = R \omega cos(\omega t)+\ell sin(\phi)\dot{\phi}$$

So my question is, mathematically, how do I justify, that I just take the derivative of the second term in each equation, as it was dependent of $t$ (Which is obviously is), and the just put a $\dot{\phi}$ outside?

Comment: consider phi as a function of t

Comment: But is that just it?
Making it dependent of $t$, and then I'm able to move it outside? It just seems so unmathematically, that's all :)

Comment: a suggestion for a minor correction: the second equation containing a derivative should by \dot{y} =, not \dot{x} =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi$ is a function of $t$, then $x$, for example, is written as
$$
x(t)=R\cos(\omega t)+\ell\sin(\phi(t)).
$$
Applying the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}x(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}R\cos(\omega t)+\frac{d}{d\phi}\ell\sin(\phi)\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t)\\
&=-R\omega\sin(\omega t)+\ell\cos(\phi)\dot{\phi}.
\end{align}
$$